# Ask for admin password when an ordinary user tries to perform admin only tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization, cancancan

I have an application built using Ruby on Rails. I use Devise for authentication and CanCanCan for authorization.

My users have two roles, **admin** and **common** user. Admin can do everything on the system and common can do limited tasks.

Now a need that everytime a **common** user tries to do something that needs **admin privileges** the application asks for an **admin password to authorize** only that operation.

I have made a research about the topic, but nothing relevant have been found.

I want to know if anyone have done something like this before and how, or if you have suggestions of other approaches to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you have only *one* admin? Or there are some of them? If second, then you want the user to input *ANY* admin password? Or both password and admin username (like it does in Win for example)

Comment: I have more than one admin and the user must enter the username and password of an admin user . Or maybe you have another suggestion, it will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to create a view and a field in database for those purposes.

You can add a field `authorized_as_admin_at` with a `datetime` type to the `users` table.

When you realize that the user needs admin access you:

1. Check if `authorized_as_admin_at` was not more than N hours/minutes ago (this method should be in `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` or smth identical in your case if you have more complex structure).
2. If it was, allow them to do what they want, otherwise:
3. Save the request path in the cookie
4. Redirect them to the page where they can input admin credentials
5. If credentials are right, you set `autorized_as_admin_at` to a current time
6. Redirect them to the path stored in the cookie.

You can try to store smth like this in session, but that does not look very secure.

Comment: Seems a great solution, I will try it out. Thank you so much.